# How to make vertical line in header latex?

Tags: header-footer, line

How to get the vertical line in center of header like this ?[image: header]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! In the header specifications, you can use something like `\rule[-0.4cm]{0.4pt}{1cm}` (adjust the exact values to your needs) or put the right-hand side in a `tabular{| p{some length} }`.

Comment: thank you so much .. it's works ..